# Case Sensitive with Entity Framework Core 7 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, attributes, case-sensitive

I create a database with Entity Framework Core 7 code-first. I look at other questions, but none of them have a concrete answer. I try to save these two names as different rows to my table:

```
Male & male
```

This is my class for attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CaseSensitive : Attribute
{
        public CaseSensitive()
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
        }

        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

This is my db model:

```
public sealed class Gender : AggregateRoot, IAuditableEntity
{
    private Gender(Guid id, ItemName name) : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
        ModificationReason ??= Reason.Create("Default").Value;
    }

    private Gender()
    {
    }

    [Required]
    [CaseSensitive]
    public ItemName Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatedOnBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOnUtc { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedOnBy { get; set; }
    public Reason ModificationReason { get; set; }
}
```

This is EF Core `DbContext` from version 6.0+:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add
        (new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<CaseSensitive, bool>
        ("CaseSensitive", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().IsEnabled));
}
```

But this doesn't work in EF Core v7 anymore. How can I make it work with EF Core 7?

Comment: Can you please explain `does not work`? Also `AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention`  seems to be from `System.Data.Entity` namespace which means it is for older iteration of EF, not the Core one.

Comment: The code inside OnModelCreating for making the Conventions. 
All of this code is from the old project (EF Version 6) which I am trying to bring into the EF Version 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the EF6 implementation would have worked, but to set case sensitivity for a column in the database you want to set the Collation for the column to a _CS (Case Sensitive) rather than a _CI (Case Insensitive) collation. Some databases use _CS by default, but many like SQL Server default to _CI.

Unfortunately at this time EF Core doesn't expose an attribute way of specifying collation, but you can set it explicitly at the OnModelCreating stage or via an EntityTypeConfiguration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().Property(c => c.Name)
.UseCollation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS");
```

You can create and handle your own Collation attribute as well:

```
internal class CollationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Collation { get; private set; }

    public CollationAttribute(string collation)
    {
        Collation = collation;
    }
}
```

Then in the entity:

```
[Collation("SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS")] // Consider declaring constants
public ItemName Name { get; set; }
```

Then in your DbContext, add the following code:

```
private void checkForCollation(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            var memberInfo = property.PropertyInfo ?? (MemberInfo)property.FieldInfo;
            if (memberInfo == null) continue;
        
            string collate = (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(memberInfo, typeof(CollateAttribute)) as CollateAttribute)?.Collation;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(collate)) continue;

            property.SetCollation(collate);
        }
}
```

... and call checkForCollation(modelBuilder) within the OnModelCreating handler override for the DbContext.